# Details JPanel with variable length fields

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a Panel which contains N rows and 2 columns, where the first column is a label with a variable length but within certain limits (it varies length according to Language), while the second column contains fields with possibly very long text.

I've tried with GridBagLayout using NetBeans however the results are messy when scaling the panel or adding very long fields..
below a screenshot of the JPanel to see what I mean:

[image]

I'd like the left column to be spaced from the left border, the first column to never resize to a smaller value than it's longest label (labels must always be readable), while the second column should visualize up to its available horizontal space and then show dots (and not crop the text).

What's also boring is that although I defined NorthWest for orientation the Panel shows vertically aligned in the center

**EDIT**: I have used TableColumnAdjuster to use table rows instead of labels for my values so that I can select the values with the mouse.
I still have the rows however fit the length of the text and not of the containing Panel:

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    static JTable table;
    MyTableModel myTableModel = new MyTableModel();

    static class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private String[] columnNames =
        {
            "Name", "Value"
        };
        private Object[][] data =
        {
            { "Subject", "very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long subject"},
            { "Date", "" },
            { "Location", "" },
            { "Status", "" },
            { "Notes", "" }
        };

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()
        { return columnNames.length; }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount()
        {  return data.length; }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {  return columnNames[col]; }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {  return data[row][col]; }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int c)
        { return getValueAt(0, c).getClass(); }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
        { return false; }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
        {        }
    }

    public TestPanel()
    {
        table = new JTable(myTableModel);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
        tca.adjustColumns();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(table);
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        panel.add(Box.createGlue(), constraints);
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new TestPanel());
        frame.setSize(300, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

while TableColumnAdjuster is from [TableColumnAdjuster](http://www.camick.com/java/source/TableColumnAdjuster.java).. what I get is still as below

[image]

Comment: Why not just use a JTable?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an incorrect usage of the `GridBagLayout`.

1. To push all the content to the top, either wrap the `GridBagLayout` panel into another panel (like a `BorderLayout` panel in the `NORTH` position) or add a component at the bottom which takes all the extra space
2. For all components in the first column, set `weightx` to 0 while on the second one, set it to something bigger than 0.
3. To add some space between the left border and the labels, simply use `insets`

Here is an example illustrating this:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Gridbag {

    public void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String label = "Label " + (i + 1);
            StringBuilder fieldValue = new StringBuilder();
            int r = 1 + random.nextInt(4);
            for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
                fieldValue.append("Some long value that may be very long in some cases");
            }
            addField(panel, label, fieldValue.toString());
        }
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        panel.add(Box.createGlue(), constraints);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addField(JPanel panel, String label, String fieldValue) {
        GridBagConstraints labelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        labelGBC.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
        labelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        GridBagConstraints fieldGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        fieldGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        fieldGBC.weightx = 1.0;
        fieldGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        panel.add(new JLabel(label), labelGBC);
        panel.add(new JLabel(fieldValue), fieldGBC);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Gridbag().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried using your solution combined with a JTable.. however it doesn't work as the horizontal size remains cropped by the JFrame.. see my edit above..

Comment: @dendini this approach is rather quite different from the one you first exposed. It would be more appropriate if you could create a new question. FWIW: don't use `static` unless absolutely necessary, JTable should be wrapped in a JScrollPane. Don't know what this TableColumnAdjuster should do.

Comment: *"To add some space between the left border and the labels, simply use insets"*  Why not add an `EmpytyBorder` to the panel?

Comment: @AndrewThompson That works too of course. Since GridBagLayout offers that feature directly, I used it. Should I favor the use of empty borders over the `GridBagConstraints.insets`?

Comment: No.  I just rarely use insets.  I should have phrased it as 'one alternative is..'.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JTable with two columns and a [TableColumnAdjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) or a [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) in order to adjust the width of the columns to the longest content.

Comment: I tried with a TableColumnAdjuster however now the size adjusts based on text length and not Panel horizontal size.. see the edit to my question

Comment: Add a JScrollPane. The width of your JFrame is too short. Try `frame.setSize(800, 800);` and this:
`public TestPanel(){
        table = new JTable(myTableModel);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
        tca.adjustColumns();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scp = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel);
    }
`

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve it is to use 3 panels in a 'nested layout'.  The panels would be laid out as follows.

1. Uses `BorderLayout` for the outer panel, it contains panels 2 & 3.
2. Uses a single column `GridLayout` - put in `BorderLayout.LINE_START`
3. Uses a single column `GridLayout` - put in `BorderLayout.CENTER`